Error when starting devcontainers in VSCode
I am using devcontainers for a project in vscode with WSL, since yesterday I got an error that doesn't let met to start the devcontainers.
The error in log shows that when trying to get the content of file product.json:
[2024-05-04T04:45:06.972Z] Start: Run in container: cat '/home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/b58957e67ee1e712cebf466b995adf4c5307b2bd/product.json'
[2024-05-04T04:45:06.975Z] Stop (3 ms): Run in container: cat '/home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/b58957e67ee1e712cebf466b995adf4c5307b2bd/product.json'
[2024-05-04T04:45:06.981Z] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Kz (c:\Users\juanp\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0\dist\extension\extension.js:225:1273)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Oue (c:\Users\juanp\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0\dist\extension\extension.js:221:4028)
    at async Nl (c:\Users\juanp\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0\dist\extension\extension.js:201:4302)
    at async bpe (c:\Users\juanp\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0\dist\extension\extension.js:275:6649)
    at async MN (c:\Users\juanp\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.362.0\dist\extension\extension.js:278:5396)

The file 'product.json' in container is empty which is causing the error.
In docker-compose.yml file i have the devcontainers, PostgreSQL, and rabbitmq services:
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:1-3.9-bullseye
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace:cached
    # Other configuration options for the Python container
    command: sleep infinity
    links:
      - frontend
    environment:
      - TZ=Etc/GMT-5
    networks:
      - mnet

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-14
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace:cached
    # Other configuration options for the TypeScript container
    command: sleep infinity
    environment:
      - TZ=Etc/GMT-5
    networks:
      - mnet

  postgres-db:
    container_name: postgres-db
    image: postgres:16
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpwd
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    networks:
      - mnet
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.9
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=radmin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rpassword
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - mnet

volumes:
  db-data:
  rabbitmq-data:

networks:
  mnet:
    driver: bridge

There is a folder called .devcontainer and inside there is two folders, one called backcontainer which has the devcontainer.json file, the same with the other folder called frontcontainer.
backcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Backend",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../../docker-compose.yml"],
    "service": "backend",
    "shutdownAction": "none",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/backend"
}

frontcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Frontend",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../../docker-compose.yml"],
    "service": "frontend",
    "shutdownAction": "none",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/frontend"
}

I tried rebuilding the containers backend and frontend ,also deleting that containers but i got the same result.
I tried with the solution here but stills fail.
I have another project with devcontainers and is working fine, but in this case i don't know what else to modify.
update 1: When i deleted the containers and start again setting up the project, I have no problem with the first devcontainer i start, I mean, after delete and rebuild and open the frontcontainer it starts without problem but the backcontainer fails; and the same when i start the backcontainer first the frontcontainer fails.

Is this of help?: Can not start devcontainer: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input parsing product.json #8624  or VSCode / Docker devcontainer.json Issue.

Yeah @Luuk i tried with the solution in there, but still the same result.
I updated the question with that. Thank you.

I downgrade VSCode from  version 1.89 (april 2024) to 1.88 (march 2024), now both devcontainers starts.
Also disabled automatic updates with this method: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_how-do-i-opt-out-of-vs-code-autoupdates
